# How to perform two COUNT(*) fetches in one query?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a MySQL table

```
id | string
------------------------------
 1 | one, two, three
 2 | two, three, five
 3 | one, three, four
 4 | three, five
 5 | one, two, three
 6 | two, three, five
 7 | one, three, four
 8 | one, three, five
 9 | two, three, four, five
10 | one, two, three, five
```

and I want to fetch the ratio of elements that contain the substring `three` in the column `string`. I could easily perform two queries and divide them manually:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `string` LIKE '%three%'
```

and divide that by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`
```

But how could I perform this with only one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM with an IF to give 1 or 0 within the brackets:-

```
SELECT SUM(IF(`string` LIKE '%three%', 1, 0))/COUNT(*)  
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Select with if condition where if condition is true then return `1` other wise `0`. Here `count(*)` return total number or record.

```
SELECT (SUM(IF(`string` LIKE '%three%', 1, 0)) * 100)/COUNT(*)  
FROM `table`
```

Comment: What it return and what you want?

Comment: Sorry, confused some answers. This returns proper result.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still comparing results (especially the performance times).

Comment: I chose @Kickstart's answer as it was postet 10 minutes earlier than this one. But +1 and thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select sum(case when string like '%three%' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) from table.
```

Comment: Doesn't return proper result (compared to performing two queries and manually divide one by the other). This query returns `0.0000`.

Comment: The DISTINCT is not required here

Comment: Edited my answer.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(find_in_set('three', replace(`string`, ' ', '')) > 0) * 100 / count(*) as percentage
from your_table
```

But you should consider changing your table design. Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: this fails for current data form of `'string'` field.

Comment: @juergend Thanks for the advice about the bad table design. This table is an OLAP intermediate table where an ETL process is performed on. I only want to make some pre-calculations.

Comment: This doesn't return a proper result (compared to performing both queries and manually calculating the result).